# Magento 2 - Data Migration Tool, unknown column store_id in customer_entity_varchar after data migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool, magento2.4

I am trying to migrate a CE 1.9.4.5 site to CE 2.4.0 and have installed the data migration tool.
I managed to migrate both Settings and data successfully.
My orders, products, settings etc .. where successfully migrated
But when i try to perform **reindex** after successful migration, following error occurs

```
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.store_id' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `u`.* FROM ( (SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `customer_entity_varchar` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('111', '479', '113', '114', '118', '563', '533', '514', '927', '982')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `customer_entity_int` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('119', '940', '941', '937', '117', '120')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `customer_entity_text` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('112', '115', '116', '121', '122', '123', '926', '530')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('965')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `customer_entity_datetime` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('565', '566')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `customer_entity_decimal` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '3') AND (attribute_id IN ('942')) AND (`store_id` IN ('2', 0))) ) AS `u` ORDER BY `store_id` ASC
```

The same sql error is shown when i take the **category menu** in backend admin panel.

Note. I checked in my old magento 1.9.4.5 site, there also store_id column is not present in customer_entity_varchar table, but everything is working perfectly there. 
Tried migrating data again in a freshly installed magento 2, but no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all thank you for the response.
I checked the database table eav_entity_type, in the field entity_type_code for catalog_category and the entity_type_id is 9.

Place this id as follow in the query:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute 
SET  entity_type_id = 9
WHERE entity_attribute_id IN (SELECT entity_attribute_id FROM (
    SELECT eea.*
    FROM `eav_entity_attribute` AS eea
    JOIN `eav_attribute` AS ea ON eea.`attribute_id` = ea.`attribute_id` 
    WHERE ea.`entity_type_id` =  9
) as x);
```

It's working after I did a flush (php bin/magento cache:flush).
Thanks for the solution.

Best regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE eav_entity_attribute 
SET  entity_type_id = {entity_type_id_you_need}
WHERE entity_attribute_id IN (SELECT entity_attribute_id FROM (
    SELECT eea.*
    FROM `eav_entity_attribute` AS eea
    JOIN `eav_attribute` AS ea ON eea.`attribute_id` = ea.`attribute_id` 
    WHERE ea.`entity_type_id` =  {entity_type_id_you_need}
) as x);
```

{entity_type_id_you_need} you can check in `eav_entity_type` (entity_type_code = 'catalog_category')